# Changing value of a cell with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem changing the value of a cell in a HTML table. I am just messing around with JavaScript because I have never used it. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var name = "Requiem";
    var health = 100;
    var strength = 1;
    var agility = 1;
    var intelligence = 1;
    var gold = 50;
    var Class = "Warrior";

    document.getElementsByName('Name').innerHTML = name;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Health</td>
      <td>Strength</td>
      <td>Agility</td>
      <td>Intelligence</td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>Class</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td name="Name"></td>
      <td name="Health"></td>
      <td name="Strength"></td>
      <td name="Agility"></td>
      <td name="Intelligence"></td>
      <td name="Gold"></td>
      <td name="Class"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is two fold.

1. Your script tag is in the head and runs immediately. Only tags that have been processed before the script will be available to manipulate. You can fix this by moving your script tag below the `<td name="Name"></td>` tag or delaying the code with something like [jQuery's document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) (requires jQuery).
2. [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) containing all the elements with the specified name. To manipulate the first element with this name, you can use `document.getElementsByName("Name")[0]`.

**Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Health</td>
            <td>Strength</td>
            <td>Agility</td>
            <td>Intelligence</td>
            <td>Gold</td>
            <td>Class</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td name="Name"></td>
            <td name="Health"></td>
            <td name="Strength"></td>
            <td name="Agility"></td>
            <td name="Intelligence"></td>
            <td name="Gold"></td>
            <td name="Class"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        var name = "Requiem";
        var health = 100;
        var strength = 1;
        var agility = 1;
        var intelligence = 1;
        var gold = 50;
        var Class = "Warrior";

        document.getElementsByName('Name')[0].innerHTML = name;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another option to jQuery's document ready is JS's onreadystatechange

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
// do stuff
}
}

Answer (score 1):

[`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (notice that it's `Elements` rather than `Element`, so you have to specify which element you'd like to modify.

In this case, there's only one element, so you only need to access the first in the list:

```
document.getElementsByName("Name")[0].innerHTML = name;
```

```js
var name = "Requiem";
var health = 100;
var strength = 1;
var agility = 1;
var intelligence = 1;
var gold = 50;
var Class = "Warrior";

document.getElementsByName('Name')[0].innerHTML = name;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Health</td>
      <td>Strength</td>
      <td>Agility</td>
      <td>Intelligence</td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>Class</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td name="Name"></td>
      <td name="Health"></td>
      <td name="Strength"></td>
      <td name="Agility"></td>
      <td name="Intelligence"></td>
      <td name="Gold"></td>
      <td name="Class"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>


</html>
```